# How to recognize when Google Chrome sends a desktop notification c++

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome

I am making a program that opens a website called Smashladder (https://www.smashladder.com/netplay?tab=matches), initiates matchmaking and then opens the emulator and basically does all the steps to connect to the opponent. When you match with someone, it sends a desktop notification (at least mine does). I want to have the program halt until the notification is sent then continue the program. How would I be able to have that information in a bool form (i.e notification was sent (t/f))?
edit: This is being made on windows 10.

Comment: From the C++ tag, I assume the program is external to Chrome? That makes the OS relevant; you would need inter-process communication.

Comment: do you have any ideas on that?